# ValueError: could not convert string to float Using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking to remove all the non numerical character, and convert the same to float type, But whenever any String character comes up , it gives the Error as "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Please suggest how to resolve it .

Input File

```
col1           col2  

122.45         NaN
Ninety Five    3585/-
9987           178@#?
225 Nine       1983.86
Twelve         7363*
```

**Output File**

```
col1           col2  

122.45         NaN
NaN            3585
9987           178
225            1983.86
NaN            7363
```

Code i am using :

```
df[['col1','col2']] = df[['col1','col2']].replace('([^\d/.])', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Getting the Error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

Comment: Try with the pattern `'[^\d\.]'` and add `.replace('', np.nan)` like so: `df[['col1','col2']].replace('([^\d\.])', '', regex=True).replace('',np.nan).astype(float)`

Comment: @WholeBrain -  Gives the same Error when it comes to the row containing value "One Lakh Two Thousand Three  hundred & Twenty Paise"

Comment: It works for my part. Did you add the second `replace` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a raw string (with the `r` in front) for regex patterns, or double backslash (`\\`) escapes. Also you need `\.` to match literal `.` characters, not `/.`:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].replace('(-?[^\d\.])', '', regex=True).replace('', float('NaN')).astype(float)
```

Comment: @Willdasilva -  Using the above lines as well Gives the same Error when it comes to the row containing value "One Lakh Two Thousand Three hundred & Twenty Paise"

Comment: @AnuragDabas -  When we have the all characters as Alpha in row values, For Eg. "One Lakh Two Thousand Three hundred & Twenty Paise" It still gives the same Error.

Comment: @Manz so `df[['col1','col2']]=df[['col1','col2']].replace('([^\d\.])', '', regex=True).replace('',float("NaN"),regex=True).astype(float)` doesn't work?

Comment: @willdasilva -  Any suggestion on if having the row value as "-122.45", Its not working in this case, how to resolve the same.

Comment: @AnuragDabas - Thanks for the Answer , Its working but when we have the row values as "-122.45" it doesn't works , gives the same value as output.

Comment: @Manz I have edited the answer to support negative numbers

Comment: @WillDaSilva -  Thanks for the Suggestion , But i am looking to remove negative characters.